# Can't draw a continuous line in Texture paint

Tags: texturing, draw-mode

I am trying to draw a line and all I get is a series of diffused dots. I am using 2.81, on Windows 10. My UV size is 1048 x 1048, and the brush settings are:
Strenght: 1.000
Mix
Brush: Color type Color, Options Affect Alpha checked.
Radius: 1px (I also tried 5, 15 px and some more)
Stroke: Space, Spacing 1%, Jitter 0.000, Input samples 1
Falloff: Custom (default)
Display: All set to 33% (default)
I don't know if I am missing some parameter setting, and I will be glad to share the file if someone is willing to help.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the result? Can you also try using the stroke type 'line' and 'curve' and see what result you get?

Comment: I don't know how to upload a jpg file in here. Can you give me instructions? I also tried Line and Curve. In either case, the drawing starts with a few diffused dots and depending on the number of samples or some other parameter will not end where is supposed to end. Also as background information, I made a simple test design, and the drawing worked just fine, using the same UV size and parameters as far as I was able to check. Therefore I see two possibilities: Either there is a parameter I am not checking somewhere or the design itself is creating the problem. I'll keep looking for your comm